# How can I run a command line command from within a ruby file?

Tags: ruby, file, terminal, command

I have a gem installed that displays a ascii image of a train moving across the terminal screen when someone types "ls". I also have a file called runner.rb.

If it's possible, how can I input the "ls" command to the terminal from within the ruby file?

Comment: Check our [5 ways to run commands in ruby](http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5-ways-to-run-commands-from-ruby/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmd = "ls > somefile.txt"
system( cmd )
```

or even just simply

```
system( "ls" )
```

Thus, you can use system.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ( **`** ) character to execute Linux commands from ruby file.

**e.g.**

```
`ls` ## OR `whoami` etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute the command as if you were sitting in the shell (so its output displays, etc.), use `system`.

```
> system('ls')
Look        At        All
My          Cool      Files
=> true
```

If you want to capture the output for use, use backticks.

```
> files = `ls`
=> "Look\nAt\nAll\nMy\nCool\nFiles\n"
```

You can interpolate in backticks if you want to (and obviously in the string you pass to `system`).